# Loading Java file through Oracle SQL Developer tool

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm new to *Oracle SQL Developer*. I have an Oracle database which is connected via Oracle SQL Developer tool. I have a DB function which in turn calls a Java method. I have created a DB function under the Function tab. I'm trying to load the Java method under the Java tab, but it is giving the below error.

> ```
> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-29516: Aurora assertion failure: Assertion
> failure at joez.c:3377  Bulk load of method java/lang/Object.<init>
> failed; insufficient shm-object space ORA-06512: at line 1
> ```

Can anyone help me to load this file into the SQL Developer tool please?

Comment: The error text for ORA-29516 indicates you need to contact Oracle support, unfortunately. A web search suggests a DB parameter that might work around it (`JAVA_JIT_ENABLED=FALSE`) or an OS-level change to `/etc/fstab`. In any case it doesn't appear to be something you're doing wrong. You should talk to your DBA in the first instance; there should be logs and trace files on the server they can use to investigate further, probably with Oracle support.

Comment: Here's a discussion on forums.oracle.com that might help: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1104718 (it suggests setting the parameter mentioned by @AlexPoole)

Comment: Thanks Alex and Frank. I will try out the suggested approaches and update here.

Answer (score 0):

### Environment

- `Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production`
- Docker
- Linux - `/bin/bash`

## Solution

```
SQL> show parameter java
NAME                                 TYPE           VALUE
------------------------------------ -----------    -------------
java_jit_enabled                        boolean     TRUE
java_max_sessionspace_size              integer     0
java_pool_size                          big integer 0
java_soft_sessionspace_limit            integer     0

SQL > alter session set java_jit_enabled=FALSE;
Session altered.

SQL >  Alter system set java_jit_enabled=FALSE scope=both;
System altered

SQL > shut immediate
SQL > startup
```

*Note: I also modified the `/dev/shm` files but I think this didn't work*

#### Links

- http://idba-oracle.blogspot.com/2013/02/ora-29516-aurora-assertion-failure.html
- https://oradbvn.wordpress.com/2013/08/13/new-jvm-jit-feature-in-11g-may-cause-ora-29516-error-on-linux/